# Android Contacts simple library?

Tags: java, android, contacts

is there any simple library for managing contacts on Android platform for 1.x and 2.x?

I have found http://code.google.com/p/contactslib/ but it's not for 1.x.

tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very simple, but you could toy around with the android.provider class. It should work with 1.x.

Comment: I was looking around but I am really hoping for something simple-lib-alike. Tnx.

Comment: I really cannot stop wondering that there isn't one library written for simply managing contacts :) that is a revelation !